# How to get MSP Recaptcha Module on custom Form?

Tags: magento2.2, captcha

I have a custom form inside a modal in a configurable product page which requires MSP Google ReCaptcha to be implemented. I tried to include the Recaptcha block in my layout file but it is not showing up.

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-modal" template="Vendor_module::custom-modal.phtml" >
     <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" name="product.info.options.swatches_inside_modal"   />
 </block>
```

If anyone knows how to solve this let me know.

Comment: You need to give us some more info.. Where  do you need to put it? Which code are you writing? Where are you writing it?

Comment: Hello @RaülVila  . Im trying to get the recaptcha module on a custom modal in configurable product page, where the customer has the ability to request a notification mail when an out of stock product comes back in stock. I have the modal running with the form but when I try to include recaptcha Block in my layout file, it doesnt show up

Comment: @magento_practitioner check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using @mahmoudismail answer to add reCaptcha to your own module:

**etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_YOUR_FORM_NAME_index_post">
        <observer name="msp_captcha" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Provider\Failure\YOUR_FORM_NAMEObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<!--    Setup redirect-->
    <virtualType name="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\YOUR_FORM_NAME"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\SimpleUrlProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">events/index/index</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>


    <virtualType name="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Provider\Failure\YOUR_FORM_NAMEObserver"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\ObserverRedirectFailure">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="redirectUrlProvider"
                      xsi:type="object">YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\YOUR_FORM_NAME</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

<!--    Check an enable config -->
    <virtualType name="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Provider\IsCheckRequired\Frontend\YOUR_FORM_NAME"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\IsCheckRequired">
        <arguments>
<!--            Commented out to eliminate need for a system config-->
<!--            <argument name="enableConfigFlag"-->
<!--                      xsi:type="string">msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled_YOUR_SETTING</argument>-->
            <argument name="area" xsi:type="string">frontend</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>


    <virtualType name="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Observer\Frontend\YOUR_FORM_NAMEObserver"
                 type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\ReCaptchaObserver">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="isCheckRequired"
                      xsi:type="object">YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Provider\IsCheckRequired\Frontend\YOUR_FORM_NAME</argument>
            <argument name="failureProvider"
                      xsi:type="object">YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Provider\Failure\YOUR_FORM_NAMEObserver</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

<!--    Adds YOUR_FORM_NAME enabled to reCaptcha module settings-->
    <type name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\LayoutSettings">
        <plugin
            name="YOUR_NAMESPACE_YOUR_MODULE_recaptcha"
            type="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Plugin\Recaptcha\LayoutSettings"
            sortOrder="1"
            disabled="false"
        />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/Recaptcha/LayoutSettings.php**

```
<?php

    namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Plugin\Recaptcha;


    /**
     * Class LayoutSettings
     * @package YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Plugin\Recaptcha
     */
    class LayoutSettings
    {
        /**
         * Enable the recaptcha for form
         * Use a system config (optional)
         *
         * @param \MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\LayoutSettings $subject
         * @param $result
         * @return bool
         */
        public function afterGetCaptchaSettings(
            \MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\LayoutSettings $subject,
            $result

        ) {

            $result['enabled']['YOUR_FORM_NAME'] = true;
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

**Add to your forms layout where appropriate**

```
 <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-"
                   template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">

                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                                <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">YOUR_FORM_NAME</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

**Output the reCaptcha div in your form**

```
<?= $this->getChildHtml('msp-recaptcha') ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**How to get MSP ReCaptcha Module on Custom Form:**

You need to implement below code in MSP Module, so please follow below steps.

> 1- MSP/ReCaptcha/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="enabled_custom_modal" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="240" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
  <label>Use in Custom Modal</label>
   <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
   <depends>
     <field id="enabled">1</field>
   </depends>
</field>
```

> 2- MSP/ReCaptcha/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<!-- Custom Modal Form -->
<virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\CustomModalForm"
             type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\SimpleUrlProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">custommodal/index/index</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\CustomModalFormObserver"
             type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\ObserverRedirectFailure">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="redirectUrlProvider"
                  xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\RedirectUrl\CustomModalForm</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\IsCheckRequired\Frontend\CustomModalForm"
             type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\IsCheckRequired">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="enableConfigFlag"
                  xsi:type="string">msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled_custom_modal</argument>
        <argument name="area" xsi:type="string">frontend</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\Frontend\CustomModalFormObserver"
             type="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\ReCaptchaObserver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="isCheckRequired"
                  xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\IsCheckRequired\Frontend\CustomModalForm</argument>
        <argument name="failureProvider"
                  xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\CustomModalFormObserver</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

> 3- MSP/ReCaptcha/Model/Config.php

```
const XML_PATH_ENABLED_FRONTEND_CUSTOM_MODAL = 'msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled_custom_modal';

/**
 * Return true if enabled on frontend request product
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnabledFrontendCustomModal()
{
    if (!$this->isEnabledFrontend()) {
        return false;
    }

    return (bool) $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::XML_PATH_ENABLED_FRONTEND_CUSTOM_MODAL);
}
```

> 4- MSP/ReCaptcha/etc/Model/LayoutSettings.php

```
/**
 * Return captcha config for frontend
 * @return array
 */
public function getCaptchaSettings()
{
    return [
        'siteKey' => $this->config->getPublicKey(),
        'size' => $this->config->getFrontendSize(),
        'badge' => $this->config->getFrontendPosition(),
        'theme' => $this->config->getFrontendTheme(),
        'lang' => $this->config->getLanguageCode(),
        'enabled' => [
            'login' => $this->config->isEnabledFrontendLogin(),
            'create' => $this->config->isEnabledFrontendCreate(),
            'forgot' => $this->config->isEnabledFrontendForgot(),
            'contact' => $this->config->isEnabledFrontendContact(),
            'custom_modal' => $this->config->isEnabledFrontendCustomModal(), // New Line added
        ]
    ];
}
```

> 5- MSP/ReCaptcha/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_custommodal_index_post">
   <observer name="msp_captcha" instance="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\Frontend\CustomModalFormObserver" />
</event>
```

> 6- MSP/ReCaptcha/etc/config.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <msp_securitysuite_recaptcha>
            <backend>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
                <size>normal</size>
                <theme>light</theme>
            </backend>
            <frontend>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
                <size>normal</size>
                <type>standard</type>
                <position>inline</position>
                <theme>light</theme>
                <lang></lang>
                <enabled_login>1</enabled_login>
                <enabled_forgot>1</enabled_forgot>
                <enabled_contact>1</enabled_contact>
                <enabled_create>1</enabled_create>
                <enabled_custom_modal>1</enabled_custom_modal> // New Line Added
            </frontend>
        </msp_securitysuite_recaptcha>
    </default>
</config>
```

Now Create xml file `custommodal_index_index.xml` in:

> 7- MSP/ReCaptcha/view/frontend/layout/custommodal_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-"
                   template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">

                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                                <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">custom_modal</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```